# I need a nested route in react router V5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

my task is to want a nested route in the **access/** route means I have a parent route **access/** so I need a nested in this route like **/access/add-team** this nested I want to do in one click of a button mean I'm my access/ route component I have I one button called **Add Team** when someone clicks on that button I am pushing to that user on this **/access/add-team** route so the route is getting change based on click but my add team component is net getting render what I am missing I am not sure I have added that every this in **Layout.js** file my component are present in **Layout.js** let me know what I need to add to work fine this also I added complete code link bellow
AppRoutes.js

```
const Layout = lazy(() => import("./Layout"));
const PageNotFound = lazy(() => import("./PageNotFound"));

const isLoggedIn = true;
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, isLoggedIn }) => {
  return (
    <Route
      render={(props) =>
        isLoggedIn ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/login" />
      }
    />
  );
};

export const AppRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <HashRouter>
      <React.Suspense fallback={""}>
        <Switch>
          <PrivateRoute path="/" isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn} component={Layout} />
          <Route
            path="*"
            name="Not Found"
            render={(props) => <PageNotFound {...props} />}
          />
        </Switch>
      </React.Suspense>
    </HashRouter>
  );
};
```

```
function Layout(props) {
  const history = useHistory();
  const { window } = props;
  const [mobileOpen, setMobileOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleDrawerToggle = () => {
    setMobileOpen(!mobileOpen);
  };

  const drawer = (
    <div>
      <Toolbar />
      <Divider />
      <List sx={{ minWidth: 230 }}>
        {newText
          ?.filter((data) => data.permission)
          ?.map((value, index) => (
            <ListItemButton
              key={index}
              sx={{ pt: 1, pb: 1, mt: 3.5 }}
              onClick={() => history.push(value.route)}
            >
              <ListItemIcon>
                <InboxIcon />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary={value.label} />
            </ListItemButton>
          ))}
      </List>
      <Divider />
    </div>
  );

  const container =
    window !== undefined ? () => window().document.body : undefined;

  return (
    <Box sx={{ display: "flex" }}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar
        position="fixed"
        sx={{
          width: { sm: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)` },
          ml: { sm: `${drawerWidth}px` }
        }}
      >
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
            edge="start"
            onClick={handleDrawerToggle}
            sx={{ mr: 2, display: { sm: "none" } }}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h6" noWrap component="div">
            Responsive drawer
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Box
        component="nav"
        sx={{ width: { sm: drawerWidth }, flexShrink: { sm: 0 } }}
        aria-label="mailbox folders"
      >
        <Drawer
          variant="permanent"
          sx={{
            display: { xs: "none", sm: "block" },
            "& .MuiDrawer-paper": {
              boxSizing: "border-box",
              width: drawerWidth
            }
          }}
          open
        >
          {drawer}
        </Drawer>
      </Box>
      <Box
        component="main"
        sx={{
          flexGrow: 1,
          p: 3,
          width: { sm: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)` }
        }}
      >
        <Toolbar />
        <Suspense fallback={""}>
          <Switch>
            {ROUTES.map((route, idx) => {
              return route.component ? (
                <Route
                  key={idx}
                  path={route.path}
                  exact={route.exact}
                  name={route.name}
                  render={(props) => <route.component {...props} />}
                />
              ) : null;
            })}
            <Redirect exact path="/" to="access" />
            <Route
              path="*"
              name="Not Found"
              render={(props) => <PageNotFound {...props} />}
            />
          </Switch>
        </Suspense>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Comment: The code in the sandbox you linked appears to function correctly. After clicking the "add team" button the URL updated to `"/access/add-team"`. What is the issue then?

Comment: but add team component is not getting render

Comment: i want to render component that i added in routing

Comment: single route component getting render perfectly but in nested route component not getting render on button click route getting change successfully but that rout has linked with add team page that not getting render

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the `Switch` component path order and specificity matters! You want to order the routes from ***more*** specific paths to `less` specific paths. In this case you are rendering the `"/access"` path prior to any of the sub-route `"/access/***"` paths, so it is matched and rendered instead of the one really matching the path in the URL.

To fix, move the `"/access"` route config below the more specific routes.

```
export const ROUTES = [
  // move "/access" route from here
  {
    name: "addTeam",
    path: "/access/add-team",
    component: lazy(() => import("./AddTeam"))
  },
  {
    name: "addUser",
    path: "/access/add-user",
    component: lazy(() => import("./AddUser"))
  },
  // to here
  {
    name: "access",
    path: "/access",
    component: lazy(() => import("./Access"))
  },
  {
    name: "admin",
    path: "/admin",
    component: lazy(() => import("./Admin"))
  }
];
```

[image]

Comment: ok fine this approach working fine but I need to know it will not create any issue right

Comment: @devdeveloper What issue are you referring to? The path order and specificity? If you are uncertain, or don't have complete control over the order, of the paths being mapped then you could alternatively unconditionally apply the `exact` prop so paths are then ***always*** exactly matched.

Comment: I am not referring to any issue just for knowledge asking is right way or not or just temporary solution

Comment: @devdeveloper In my professional opinion, the routes in the `Switch` should ***always*** be in inverse order of specificity. If done correctly there's an effectively ZERO need for the `exact` prop to modify this behavior. This OFC, isn't an issue in RRDv6 as routes are *always* exactly matched and uses a path score instead of relaying on the specificity and order.